# Terminologie et nature des adjectifs, existence ou non des formes comparatives et superlatives

Tags: adjectifs, comparatifs, superlatifs

Il existe beaucoup d'adjectifs d'une sorte courante, comme « bon », « rapide », « commun », etc. avec lesquels il y a la possibilité d'une forme comparative et de formes superlatives (meilleur, très bon, le meilleur, plus rapide, le plus rapide, etc.). Il en existe une autre sorte pour lesquels cela n'est pas vrai, par exemple les adjectifs « immobile » et « excellent ».

1. Quelle serait la terminologie qui décrit ces deux catégories ?
2. Quels faits importants serait-il utile de connaitre en rapport avec elles (mis à part les formes irrégulières) ?

Comment: Je ne connais pas de terminologie particulière. Les adjectifs qui n'admettent (en théorie) ni comparatifs ni superlatifs sont ceux dont le sens n'admet pas de degrés. Après... on peut toujours en forcer si on veut, on peut se dire *plus ou moins* immobile et mon époque au Lycée se plaisait à ajouter des suffixes ***-issime*** à tout bout de champ... et de préférence... par dérision évidemment... (*excellentissime, uniquissime...*)

Answer (score 1):

Ces deux liens pour [*moins*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/moins+excellent.html) et [*plus*](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=plus+excellent) *excellent* montrent que dans la langue courante ces adjectives peuvent se mettre avec les formes comparatives et superlatives. Néanmoins, suivant l'usage anglais je dirais qu'une terminologie décrivant ces deux catégories pourrait s'appeller *comparabilité*, par exemple : *des adjectives (in)comparables*.

Comment: La référence « moins » est à nulle; une erreur d'amalgamation inapproprié la rend invalide; « pour le moins », « ni plus ni moins », « tout au moins », « à tout le moins », sont des expressions toutes faites et « moins » ne modifie donc jamais l'adjectif qui peut suivre. La référence sur « plus », cependant, donne des cas d'utilisation qui correspondent; seulement je crois que Linguee est beaucoup trop large dans ses choix (organismes étrangers et aussi de mauvaises traductions en français). « Plus excellent » ne se dit pas en français et il n'y a aucune raison ce commencer à le dire.

Comment: « Comparabilité » existe déjà et a pour définition « qualité de ce qui est comparable ». Il faut, pour le mot que vous cherchez la définition « caractéristique de l'adjectif qui en fait, pour une qualité trouvée selon une échelle d'intensités ou de magnitudes ou de  degrés, etc un terme exprimant l'état d'avoir cette qualité  quel que soit le points dans l' échelle ». Par exemple, « variativité » irait, en admettant d'abord l'existence de l'adjectif « variatif » et la définition des  qualités variatives. Il n'y a aucune nécessité d'empiler des quantités de concepts sur une seule forme.

Comment: Selon [ce livre d'1802](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=JNPmaTXfItIC&pg=PA418&dq=%22plus+excellent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXiKHx8q_eAhULUd4KHaX3BjIQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22plus%20excellent%22&f=false) la raison qu'*excellent* n'a pas de superlatif est que c'est le superlatif de *bon*, bien que *le mieux* est courant; le mettant dans une catégorie séparée d'*immobile*. De toute façon il se peut qu'il n'y ait pas encore une explanation grammatique, courante, et unanime pour distinguer les usages mentionnés dans la question.

Comment: @Carl Bravo pour la double exhumation : *explanation grammatique* !  ;-)

Comment: @LPH *Plus/moins excellent* sont certes discutables, mais néanmoins attestés : *Qu'on me donne l'action **la plus excellente** et pure, je m'en vois y fournir vraysemblablement cinquante vicieuses intentions*, Corneille; *La véhémence de mon article sur vous ne saurait, dites-vous, influencer votre jugement sur mes œuvres, ni vous faire trouver ma conférence **moins excellente**.*, André Gide.

Comment: Il me semble extravagant que dans un système linguistique on puisse tolérer que quelques cas hors norme, du seul fait qu'on les trouve sous la plume de sommités en matière d'expression verbale, soit automatiquement reconnus comme faisant loi ; ne les appelons plus les maîtres du langage mais les dieux ! Prenez conscience du fait  qu'un des maitres de la mathématiques moderne, Henri Lebesgue, dans une de ses démonstrations importantes dans sa théorie de l'intégrale est l'auteur d'une magnifique faute **attestée** dans la théorie des ensembles ; un homme en vaut un autre pour ainsi dire ;